# Script to append an icon to a username based on an array of users in a group, how do I create?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I'm in the process of expanding on the ranking system on a wiki that I am an administrator of, and I want to be able to:

1. Create an array of people in multiple user groups
2. Search the current page for the names on the lists
3. Append an icon to their name based on status

I know that to create the arrays, I will need to define them like:

```
var hosts = new Array("H1");
    /* Prob don't need an array for a group with one user;
    * however, will it break anything to have it?
    * There may be users added here in the future. */
var bureaucrats = new Array("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")
var admins = new Array("A1", "A2", "A3", "...")
/* There are more, abbreviating for effect. */
var superUsers = new Array("SU1", "SU2", "SU3", "SU4", "...")
/* There are more, abbreviating for effect. */
```

I can `concat()` all of the arrays initially to see if one of these users exist.

```
var ranked_users = hosts.concat(bureaucrats, admins, superUsers)
```

I can create the loop to go through the list `rankedUsers`

```
var numOfUsers=rankedUsers.length;
for (i=0;i<=numOfUsers;i++)
{
    if (rankedUsers[i]==/* Not sure */)
    {
         concat(String.fromCharCode(/* Based on group */, 00a0), rankedUsers[i])
    }
}
```

I would use codes `2776` for hosts, `2777` for bureaucrats, `2778` for admins, and `2779` for super users. (possibly going further if I declared more groups, but it would be simple to expand the pattern).
This is where I start to get stuck.. How do I find the user names on the page?
Do I use match() or search()?

Edit: I built the start of a jsfiddle to work with that can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RDmFn/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding this again after some time, I ended up having each of the groups assigned a class and then using css to prefix the image with:

```css
.group:before {
  content: '\code';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do that in JavaScript? Do it at parse time, in PHP.

You then have easy access to the namespace and title of any link object being created, and can act when needed (i.e. when namespace is 2 [User] and title is a user name belonging to a group).

Just write a simple extension using the [LinkBegin hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LinkBegin) and check `$user->getGroups()` for the groups you want to mark.

Comment: I know less about writing php than I do about css & js, and as an administrator, I don't have access to install extensions even if I could create one. :(